# How to specify version of language to be scanned in sonarqube?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, sonarqube

I am new to Sonarqube. I want to scan my python files on sonarqube with rules of Python 2.7 and not Python 3. I am specifying sonar.language=py while scanning. Is there any way to specify version of python? Also how to know what version of Python rules are set in sonarqube?

Comment: You shouldn't specify `sonar.language`. This property is deprecated and has been removed from newer SonarQube versions.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to specify that.
[A few rules are tagged with "python3"](https://rules.sonarsource.com/python/tag/python3), but they can still be relevant for you.

You can define which rules are applied by managing "quality profiles": have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/quality-profiles/).